# Is it possible to create custom JetBrain.Annotations?

Tags: resharper

I would like to know if there is a way to extend or create a custom jetbrain annotation for Resharper.

For example, I would like to create a custom annotation which does exactly what [UsedImplicitly] does but I want to call it something else. In other words, I want to create a custom annotation called [UnityAnimationEvent] but it will behave exactly like [UsedImplicitly] (i.e suppress usage warnings).
I tried inheriting from the annotation classe but it seems to be sealed.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to add custom annotations to Objects you do not have access to the source code for.

Take a look at the documentation for [External Annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html) provided by Jetbrains

Essentially, what you'll need to do is create an assembly that defines the new attribute. After that, you can use the External Annotations capability to attach it to anything you want.

Comment: mhmm... not really an answer. The question is about custom annotations and not about annotating other objects.